# systemc library can't be opened with vs 2013

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, systemc

I am new to systemc programming.For the installation, [I followed this tutorial to install and startup.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0N7571XnkRQ) I am trying to build a simple main program. However I am getting the error

> error LNK1104: cannot open file "systemc.lib".

Now with a simple directory search, I am not finding the file. However it seems that removing it causes more damages. 
 [According to this poste](http://forums.accellera.org/topic/2237-systemc-using-visual-studio-2013/) The fact that the tutorial is for vs2010 and I am using vs2013 shouldn't be a problem.

How do I move foward. What should I do. Here is the code:

```
// Hello_world is module name
SC_MODULE(hello_world) {
 SC_CTOR(hello_world) {
    // Nothing in constructor 
 }
 void say_hello() {
    //Print "Hello World" to the console.
    cout << "Hello World.\n";
    }
};

// sc_main in top level function like in C++ main 
int sc_main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
hello_world hello("HELLO");
// Print the hello world
 hello.say_hello();
 return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your second link, the reason why you don't have the library is simple: because you didn't build it. You should have the source files to build the library.